# Some doubts regarding basics of binary search

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search

```
public class sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 15};
        int target = 12;
        int ans = search(nums, target);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    static int search(int[] arr, int target){
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length - 1;
        while(start <= end){
            int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
            if (target < arr[mid]){
                end = mid -1;
            }
            else if (target > arr[mid]){
                start = mid +1;
            }
            else{
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I know it could be very lame but I'm just starting out with java and dsa.
Doubt#1 -> why aren't we using return statement in if, else if? how does the method gives out the value once it has found the number?
Doubt#2 -> kindly explain the math and reason behind int mid = start + (end+start)/2;

Comment: There *is* a `return` statement in the `if … else if … else` statement. Further, the expression is `start + (end-start)/2`, not `start + (end+start)/2`, maybe you’ll understand it when reading correctly. How do you calculate the middle of two values? Start value plus half of the distance between the points.

Answer (score 2):

Within the `if` and `else if` you're still trying to find the target element. The `if` clause is entered if the target element is smaller than the element of the array you're currently looking at. `else if` is executed if the target element is larger than the element of the array you're currently looking at. In those cases you haven't found your target element yet, so you don't want to return anything. The `else` part is executed if the current element equals the target element, so you found what you were looking for and return the index at which the target was found.

The code `int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;` calculates the middle index `mid` in a way that helps avoid integer overflow issues:

`start` is the current leftmost index of the search range.
`end` is the current rightmost index of the search range

The formula `(end - start) / 2` calculates the distance between the start and end indices and then divides it by 2 to get the halfway point. Adding start to this result gives you the actual middle index.

The reason for using `(end - start)` instead of `(end + start)` is to prevent integer overflow. If you used (end + start) and `start` and `end` were large values, adding them could potentially lead to an integer overflow problem. Subtracting them allows you to calculate the middle point without that problem.

For a more detail on how binary search works I like [this explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/)

Answer (score 1):

We don't use return statement in the if / else if because the while loop has to continue shortening the array. If we add a return statement that would break the while loop.

The method doesn't return the found value, it returns the index where the value is stored in the array.

Regarding doubt 2: the reason is we want to shorten the array so that we don't look after or before a certain value. The binary search algorithm works by halvening the array on each iteration. So if you are looking for the index of number 10 there and the current number you have checked is 6 there is no reason to look the previous numbers (that's why binary search only works in sorted arrays), so with the statement in if / else if we set boundaries (either top or bottom boundary).

Comment: so how does it returns the value of control flow statements without return ? does it throws the last value before the loop broke?

Comment: It will return the midd which will potentially be a match, if no match is found it will return -1. Invalid index. You can imagine the binary search as looking for a word in a dictionary. If you are lloking for some word starting with H there is no point in starting from thenfirst page. You open it directly in the middle and go from there.